# Using asterisk in bash command of Jenkins pipeline returns error

Tags: bash, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to execute following command in Jenkins Pipeline:

```
stage('Deploy Airflow') {
            steps{
                dir("airflow-dags") {
                    sh """
                    sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/*.py
```

But it causes error:

```
21:44:56  + sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\ \ \ \ schedule_interval=None,' './volumes/dags/*.py'
21:44:56  sed: can't read ./volumes/dags/*.py: No such file or directory
```

How do I need to change command to use ./volumes/dags/*.py instead of quoting it which causes an error?

Comment: Did you confirm a file exists that matches that glob? Looks like it quoted it...

Comment: Put the pull path to the py files.

Comment: @PaulHodges I need to apply sed command to all python files in the ./volumes/dags directory. I confirm that they exisst and run command locally: sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\ \ \ \ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/*.py which works perfect, but using it Jenkins trying to execute on "./volumes/dags/*.py" file where mask is not applied

Comment: @RamanSailopal thanks for suggestion, trying...

Comment: @RamanSailopal no luck, the same story with quoting path

Comment: Can you put the path in the example

Comment: @RamanSailopal `22:06:20  + sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\ \ \ \ schedule_interval=None,' '/home/jenkins/workspace/QA_deploy_Docker/airflow-dags/volumes/dags/*.py'
22:06:20  sed: can't read /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_deploy_Docker/airflow-dags/volumes/dags/*.py: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like it is seeing *.py as an actual file name as opposed to a wild card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the quoting layers as it's being passed through Jenkins and groovy before it gets to the shell.

Try find as a workaround.

```
find ./volumes/dags/ -name '*.py' -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' {} +
```

or maybe

```
find ./volumes/dags/ -name '*.py' -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  xargs sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,'
```

c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: You will likely need to tweak.

Comment: yep, your answer worked and there is no problem with quoting, but there is another problem. Groovy script behaves differently if it is located in the last stage (where find command does not print anything) whereas script located in the only stage where the exactly same script  with find command works well. I will ask another question. Thanks

Comment: I have posted another question regarding different behaviour of code on different pipeline stages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016885/the-same-bash-command-behaves-differently-if-it-is-located-in-different-stages-o

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution *per se*, but an explanation of what is happening here.

When you type

```
sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/*.py
```

into your shell, the shell performs *glob expansion* - seeing `*` in the command, it searches for any files matching the *glob* `./volumes/dags/*.py` and replaces the glob with a list of matching files.

So, if there were e.g. two files:

```
./volumes/dags/1.py
./volumes/dags/2.py
```

the actual command that will run is

```
sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/1.py ./volumes/dags/2.py
```

All this is correct outside of Jenkins.

However, when in Jenkins, your code:

```
   sh """
      sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/*.py
      """
```

does not involve glob expansion, so the actual `sed` command now looks like this:

```
sed -i '/schedule_interval=/c\\ \\ \\ \\ schedule_interval=None,' ./volumes/dags/*.py
```

To which `sed` correctly complains:

```
sed: can't read ./volumes/dags/*.py: No such file or directory
```

One way to fix it is to involve `find` as suggested. Another way is to involve shell:

```
   sh """ 
       bash -c "sed '...' ./volumes/dags/*.py"
      """
```